# Setting Charset on Nginx PHP virtual host not working

Tags: nginx, utf-8, iso-8859-1, php-7.2

I tried to set the Charset of a virtual host like this:

```
server {
        root /var/www/mywebsite.com;
```

...

```
        charset iso-8859-1;
        override_charset on;
```

...

```
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
                charset iso-8859-1;
                override_charset on;

        }
}
```

I have specified `charset` and `overried_charset` on both `server` and `location` and yet, it was still sending headers in UTF-8.

I had to modify the php.ini file from /etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini to specify in it `default_charset = "iso-8859-1"`.

But I would like to let my php set to UTF-8 and specify on Nginx only for only one virtual host iso-8859-1.

On Apache we can do:

```
<VirtualHost mywebsite.com:80>
...
    Header set Content-Type "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"
</VirtualHost>
```

How to do the same on Nginx?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a PHP issue not Nginx. The default PHP charset config is set to "utf-8" and you want to let it as it. So to overwrite it, add on the beginning of your script:

```
ini_set('default_charset', 'iso-8859-1');
```